# How to see a list of devices connected to my Google Nest Wifi Router

Tags: wireless-router, nest

The Google Nest Router seems not to have an admin page with a "traditional" list of connected devices, with IP Addresses, etc.  Instead it directs you to use a phone app which seems as much designed to sell you more Google products as anything else. It hides the technical information I'm looking for. I am trying to solve a problem in my network.

I simply want to see a list of the devices connected to my network, with IP Addresses, etc.

How may I do this?

UPDATE: I was about to upvote this IMHO excellent question, but it turned out to be MY OWN question from six months ago.  I can't believe Google can get away with selling a router that has no traditional admin page, but that is apparently the case.

Jeepers, creepers, all I want to do is see a list of devices connected to my router with their IP addresses.

Comment: It'd be essentially a link only answer if I posted it but https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/6263633?hl=en-SG#zippy=%2Cwith-the-google-home-app%2Cwith-the-google-wifi-app seems to say there's a device tab, on... one of two apps that google uses. If it does work, documenting it as an answer would be helpful for the next person. App based management is a common flaw in most mesh devices :(

Comment: This link seems to be out of date. There is no “favorites” icon in the app.